# forcing mobile view on all page loads

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to force mobile view on all devices that get in my website.
When I try using this method:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=400">
```

It works on my phone but does not work on my pc, it did not change anything.

this:

```
$('meta[name="viewport"]').prop('content', 'width=400');
```

Also worked on my Iphone but not on my pc.

**Note:**
I do not want to use developer tools as I want that every user that goes to my site will see the mobile view of it

Comment: In that case, why build a non-mobile version of the site at all? Just build only the mobile version and serve it to everyone?

Comment: can you just give a `width:400px` to body?

Comment: @nullptr That did not work, not even on my phone.

Comment: @JeremyThille Yes, that is what I want, but for that to look good I need to force a width to the desktop.

Comment: Why do you need to force a width on the desktop? If there's only one version of the site, it will be served everywhere. You don't need to force a width on the desktop. If you want a max-with, just encapsulate the whole thing in a div and give it `max-width:400px` (probably won't work on the whole body, but it should in a containing div)

Comment: @JeremyThille When I just use the mobile version the website does not look good because it is designed to be a mobile one that the height is bigger than width. I have tried using max-width but that did not work

Comment: Add your real code, and not just a chunk out of it.

Comment: Could you please add the relevant code and actual behaviour, instead of just describing your attempt and saying "it didn't work"? All we know is that what we suggest "didn't work". Just saying "it didn't work" [is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)...